# TYPO3 set title of fluid page object from extension

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase, fluid-layout

I want to set the the page title within my extension, so the current {page} object in the Fluid Templates will also show the set title.

`$GLOBALS['TSFE']->altPageTitle = $pageTitle;` will only set the `<title>` tag and has no impact to the {page.title}

My Primary Goal: To show the 'correct' title of a detail page within a breadcrumb.

Any ideas how to manipulate that?

Answer (score 0):

For cached pages and plugins this should work:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->page['title'] = $pageTitle;
```

Comment: Sadly no. That only sets the Page Title, not the title in the page object

Comment: Your page and plugin are cached?

Comment: Nope, also all caches cleared. Just to be clear, if you do that, the title property in the page object will change? Not just the html <title> tag?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about a {page} object in fluid, so I did it with a ViewHelper similar to the one from [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/77913255/)

```
/**
 * A view helper for setting the document title in the <title> tag.
 *
 * = Examples =
 *
 * <page.title mode="prepend" glue=" - ">{blog.name}</page.title>
 * 
 * <page.title mode="replace">Something here</page.title>
 * 
 * <h1><page.title mode="append" glue=" | " display="render">Title</page.title></h1>
 * 
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html GNU Lesser General Public License, version 3 or later
 */
class PageTitleViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper {

  /**
   * @var bool
   */
  protected $escapeOutput = false;

    /**
     * @param string $mode Method for adding the new title to the existing one.
     * @param string $glue Glue the new title to the old title with this string.
     * @param string $display If render, this tag displays it's children. By default it doesn't display anything.
     * @return string Rendered content or blank depending on display mode.
     * @author Nathan Lenz <nathan.lenz@organicvalley.coop>
     */
    public function render($mode = 'replace', $glue = ' - ', $display = 'none') {

        $renderedContent = $this->renderChildren();

        $existingTitle = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->page['title'];

        if ($mode === 'prepend' && !empty($existingTitle)) {
            $newTitle = $renderedContent.$glue.$existingTitle;
        } else if ($mode === 'append' && !empty($existingTitle)) {
            $newTitle = $existingTitle.$glue.$renderedContent;
        } else {
            $newTitle = $renderedContent;
        }

        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->page['title'] = $newTitle;
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->indexedDocTitle = $newTitle;


        if ($display === 'render') {
            return $renderedContent;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Again, its not about setting the <title> tag within the html <head> - that works, its about to overwrite the title in the page object (do a <f:debug>{_all}</f:debug> / <f:debug>{page}</f:debug> and you see the current page object)

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 since v9 has an official "Page Title API" you should use: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Seo/PageTitleApi.html#pagetitle